# Get liste of queues listen to by RabbitListener service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amqp, spring-rabbit

Can you please suggest a way to get dynamically the list of queues listen to by rabbitMQ spring RabbitListener (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener)

Here is the example of my Listener which handles messages from a lot of queues (the list can be updated in the properties file)
I want to get the list in another service dynamically :

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class GenericListener {

@RabbitListener(queues = {
                "${queue1}", "${queue2}", "${queue3}", "${queue4}", "${queue5}"
})
 public void receiveMessage(Message message) {

 }
}
```

the question specifically is : how to dynamically get bean interface RabbitListener params at runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

Give the listener an `id`; e.g. `@RabbitListener(id = "foo", ...)` then

```
((AbstractMessageListenerContainer) registry.getListenerContainer("foo")).getQueueNames();
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#container-management

> Containers created for annotations are not registered with the application context. You can obtain a collection of all containers by invoking `getListenerContainers()` on the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean. You can then iterate over this collection, for example, to stop or start all containers or invoke the `Lifecycle` methods on the registry itself, which will invoke the operations on each container.

> You can also get a reference to an individual container by using its `id`, using `getListenerContainer(String id)` — for example, `registry.getListenerContainer("multi")` for the container created by the snippet above.

> ...

Comment: thanks Gary, ca you please suggest a link to create the RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry for my spring boot app ?

Comment: It's created by the framework, you can use normal Spring mechanisms to get a reference, such as `@Autowired` as a dependency, add it as a parameter to a `@Bean` definition method, etc, etc.

Comment: thats what i did, but the list of listeners was empty, so i thought that i did it wrong

Comment: Perhaps you are doing the lookup too early; wait until the application context is fully initialized.

Comment: OK, thanks, i will force the order, as always, you rock, have a nice day man :)